# How to solve "Form 1 is not declared" error?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I got this error and my program cannot run. I change my form name from default (form 1) to Loan Payment Calculator.

BC30451 "Form 1 is not declared.' It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
Thank you.

Comment: This needs more information. How did you rename the form exactly? Did you check the code behind the form? Did you check the designer file for the form?

Comment: "Form1" is also used in the Designer.vb file.  Change it back, then right-click the word and choose Rename.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Windows Forms application, you should change:
`Application.Run(new Form1());`  to use your new name in the Program.cs Main method.
Or you can try to find from VS search all matches of Form1.

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vb.net go to Application.Designer.vb file and find where it written Form1 and changed it accordingly.